# Play embedded WAV in standalone app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, audio

I added an embedded wav file into my project, following the msdn guidelines of having it embedded into the resx file.  Since this is a standalone app, I do not want to copy files locally/install anything.

```
System.Reflection.Assembly a = System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly();
System.IO.Stream s = a.GetManifestResourceStream("myApp.mySound");
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(s);
player.Play();
```

This compiles, but the actual sound doesn't play, instead, the windows ding plays.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was able to reproduce your issue.

The following resolved it for me:

```
System.IO.Stream s = Resources.ResourceManager.GetStream("speedwarning");
SoundPlayer player = new SoundPlayer(s);
player.Play();
```

My file was "speedwarning.wav", which I added as an embedded resource.

You'll have to add "using YOUR_APP.Properties", and one thing that tripped me up is that in the Solution Explorer, under the Resources folder the file showed as 'speedwarning.wav', but the actual resource name was just 'speedwarning'. You can inspect the file "Resources.resx" to see what the name should be... or right click the project, choose properties, and find the resource in the "Resources" tab (you may have to switch the drop down to "Audio Ctrl+4")

Comment: And if your resource is in a separate assembly, don't forget that in the resource explorer you can set an access modifier per resource. So you could make the audio resource "public"... if you're OK with that.

Comment: Adding the properties and dropping the assembly did the trick.  I tried adding it to public so I assume I can revert that back.  I thank you for your assistance!

Comment: Yeah, unless you need it to be public for another reason I'd switch it back.